# Wiring meter to plug on neutral circuit breaker

Tags: meter

I am adding a new service to my pole barn. Plan to have 200 amp service. Bought a square d plug on neutral breaker box. Using 4/0 4/0 4/0 2/0 service entrance cable (aluminum).

I know where to place the two hots and the neutral.

Currently I have the 2/0 portion to the ground next to the neutral in the breaker box. Is this correct?

Where do I put the 2/0 unsheathed portion of the cable for the meter? Is that the ground from the breaker box to meter box? Do I hook it to the neutral in the meter or clamp it to the ground.[image]

Comment: Is this a *service* from the utility, or a *feeder* from somewhere else on your property?

Comment: Ummm, that's a meter socket, not a "breaker box"...

Comment: I call that a meter pan.  The power company's meter plugs in there.  Now OP, that big cable going through the conduit.  Where is the other end of it?

Comment: Where does that big cable go/ can you shoot a pic of it?